# How do `prior` and `connect` work in `matplotlib.sankey.Sankey.add`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sankey-diagram

I have a weighted directed graph ([`nx.DiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html)) that I want to plot as a Sankey diagram using Matplotlib.

I'm a bit confused about the roles of `prior` and `connect`. The [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/sankey_api.html#matplotlib.sankey.Sankey.add) say:

> prior : int
>
> Index of the prior diagram to which this diagram should be connected.

and

> connect : (int, int)
>
> A (prior, this) tuple indexing the flow of the prior diagram and the flow of this diagram which should be connected. If this is the first diagram or prior is None, connect will be ignored.

It isn't clear to me what these parameters are that I would have to specify prior twice, once in `prior` and the other time as the first element passed to `connect`.

There are [these examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/sankey_basics.html#sphx-glr-gallery-specialty-plots-sankey-basics-py) in the Matplotlib gallery, but I did not find that they illuminated much about how these parameters are really supposed to work.

I found [this tutorial](https://flothesof.github.io/sankey-tutorial-matplotlib) which did a nice job of incrementally building up some of the components. It described `connect` this way:

> It turns out that we can now give a simpler explanation of the connect argument: it says which flows (indexed in the order they were defined) should be connected. So connect should really be described as
>
> > connect = (index_of_prior_flow, index_of_current_diagram_flow) that need to be connected

But taking that understanding to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/sankey_rankine.html#sphx-glr-gallery-specialty-plots-sankey-rankine-py) proved confusing to me since I would have thought that `index_of_current_diagram_flow` would be constant across diagrams, but the example suggests otherwise.

I'm sure there is a consistent behaviour to this tool, but I don't understand it yet. How do I understand `prior` and `connect` in terms of a directed graph?

Comment: Oh no... I think I understand now. This is not great because you can only make one explicit connection per patch added, and for the patches with implicit connections you'll have to ensure that the orientation and lengths match up. Dang.

Comment: Wouldn't a [chord diagram](https://observablehq.com/collection/@d3/d3-chord) be more appropriate?